# How to get float value from modulus in PHP?

Tags: php, math, floating-point

We know `10 % 3` is `3.3333333333333333333333333`.

if i use `echo 10 % 3`, it return `1` not `3.3333333333333333333333333`.

Now how to get float value from modulus in PHP? is possible to get `3.3333333333333333333333333`?

Thanks.

Comment: You did not understand what the modulus is. Try regular division with `/`.

Comment: "We know 10 % 3 is 3.3333333333333333333333333". i don't know who knows it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's **incorrect**.

We know that `10 / 3` is `3.3333...`, notice that is `/` (division) not `%` (modulus).

The reason `10 % 3` is `1` is because `3` goes into `10` `3` times with a remainder of `1`.